# How can I avoid opening multiple elements at one time using Bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and can't figure out how to only allow the opening of one element at a time using their collapse feature.

Currently, clicking the linked image reveals the collapsed div as expected. But if you click a different linked image, the corresponding div also appears without closing the first.

What am I missing here?

Here's my HTML:

```
<section id="employees" class="text-center">
        <ul id="employee_list" class="list-unstyled list-inline">

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse1"><img src="/media/cache/5a/a3/5aa3c3ab6d4af27b6efe20a8b3d9b119.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Charles"></a>
                <h2>Charles<br><small>Owner</small></h2>
            </li>

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse4"><img src="/media/cache/0a/a1/0aa14aaa5f95ed5eb86bb0a81fec5dd6.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Kathleen"></a>
                <h2>Kathleen<br><small>Design Consultant</small></h2>
            </li>

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse2"><img src="/media/cache/f1/ad/f1adc6187d0209e5ff14ed43118ca6b8.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Carlos"></a>
                <h2>Carlos<br><small>Project Manager</small></h2>
            </li>

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse3"><img src="/media/cache/88/16/88169162a66ed65beba79b5502a7955a.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Phil"></a>
                <h2>Phil<br><small>Project Manager</small></h2>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <div id="collapse1" class="collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio">d convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero</p>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse4" class="collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum sodales vulputate. Nullam vulputate ante in posuere sodales. Quisque tempor nunc id convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero quis luctus. Quisque imperdiet ante quis mauris pharetra, eu eleifend ligula pretium. Etiam tempor libero sed lacus lacinia tristique. Nam malesuada massa eu interdum tincidunt. Aliquam pretium neque arcu, quis accumsan justo tincidunt eget.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse2" class="collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum sodales vulputate. Nullam vulputate ante in posuere sodales. Quisque tempor nunc id convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero quis luctus. Quisque imperdiet ante quis mauris pharetra, eu eleifend ligula pretium. Etiam tempor libero sed lacus lacinia tristique. Nam malesuada massa eu interdum tincidunt. Aliquam pretium neque arcu, quis accumsan justo tincidunt eget.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse3" class="collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum sodales vulputate. Nullam vulputate ante in posuere sodales. Quisque tempor nunc id convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero quis luctus. Quisque imperdiet ante quis mauris pharetra, eu eleifend ligula pretium. Etiam tempor libero sed lacus lacinia tristique. Nam malesuada massa eu interdum tincidunt. Aliquam pretium neque arcu, quis accumsan justo tincidunt eget.</p>
        </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: You need to change the class of each collapsible item to something unique

Comment: Why is that? The docs don't appear to indicate as much.

Comment: Also, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't support what you're looking for out of the box. What you'll need to do is listen to the "show.bs.collapse" event that bootstrap triggers and then collapse the others.

```
$(".employee-collapse").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
  $(".employee-collapse").not(e.target).each(function(i, el){
    if ($(el).is(":visible"))
      $(el).collapse('hide');
  });
});
```

you'll see that I added the `.employee-collapse` class to the elements just to be more specific.

```
<section id="employees" class="text-center">
        <ul id="employee_list" class="list-unstyled list-inline">

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse1"><img src="/media/cache/5a/a3/5aa3c3ab6d4af27b6efe20a8b3d9b119.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Charles"></a>
                <h2>Charles<br><small>Owner</small></h2>
            </li>

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse4"><img src="/media/cache/0a/a1/0aa14aaa5f95ed5eb86bb0a81fec5dd6.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Kathleen"></a>
                <h2>Kathleen<br><small>Design Consultant</small></h2>
            </li>

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse2"><img src="/media/cache/f1/ad/f1adc6187d0209e5ff14ed43118ca6b8.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Carlos"></a>
                <h2>Carlos<br><small>Project Manager</small></h2>
            </li>

            <li class="employee_info">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#employee_list" data-target="#collapse3"><img src="/media/cache/88/16/88169162a66ed65beba79b5502a7955a.jpg" width="175" height="175" class="img-circle" alt="Phil"></a>
                <h2>Phil<br><small>Project Manager</small></h2>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <div id="collapse1" class="collapse employee-collapse">
          <p class="employee_bio"><strong>Charles</strong> d convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero</p>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse4" class="collapse employee-collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio"><strong>Kathleen</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum sodales vulputate. Nullam vulputate ante in posuere sodales. Quisque tempor nunc id convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero quis luctus. Quisque imperdiet ante quis mauris pharetra, eu eleifend ligula pretium. Etiam tempor libero sed lacus lacinia tristique. Nam malesuada massa eu interdum tincidunt. Aliquam pretium neque arcu, quis accumsan justo tincidunt eget.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse2" class="collapse employee-collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio"><strong>Carlos</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum sodales vulputate. Nullam vulputate ante in posuere sodales. Quisque tempor nunc id convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero quis luctus. Quisque imperdiet ante quis mauris pharetra, eu eleifend ligula pretium. Etiam tempor libero sed lacus lacinia tristique. Nam malesuada massa eu interdum tincidunt. Aliquam pretium neque arcu, quis accumsan justo tincidunt eget.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse3" class="collapse employee-collapse">
            <p class="employee_bio"><strong>Phil</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum sodales vulputate. Nullam vulputate ante in posuere sodales. Quisque tempor nunc id convallis placerat. Maecenas id urna velit. Etiam et eros tristique magna adipiscing cursus a nec sem. Curabitur sagittis non libero quis luctus. Quisque imperdiet ante quis mauris pharetra, eu eleifend ligula pretium. Etiam tempor libero sed lacus lacinia tristique. Nam malesuada massa eu interdum tincidunt. Aliquam pretium neque arcu, quis accumsan justo tincidunt eget.</p>
        </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: So only the accordion is supported by default?